# Role of Mn in Perovskites

Tags: material-science

Good Day everyone!i don't if its the right site to ask this, but by the way, right now i'm searching for possible research in magnetoresistance properties of perovskite. So far, i already know the effect of Mn in Perovskite, it enhance the ferromagnetic properties of the material. And Manganites in Ferromagnetic State possessed magnetoresistance in magnetic field. So my question is if i increase the Mn content, what will happen to the magnetoresistance or to the resistivity of the materials? Gradually decreased? and why? Please provide Trusted Articles to support that data! thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe also try Earth Science. When I read the Perovskite Wiki page I felt like my brain was going to explode. Can you maybe say what your motivation is: presumably you're talking about mangnite inclusions in Perovskite, and if current can find a path through a the inclusions in a lump of perovskite, then the simple answer is yes, evidently the more such paths there are through the lump, the more the resistance to the total current will be modulated by the $\vec{B}$ field. To get more quantitative than this, one needs to ask what form the inclusions take, how and whether they link up, ....

Comment: ... and this would seem to be knowledge that Earth scientists would know rather than physicists.

Comment: Actually, I find it really unlikely that Earth Science folks would get down into this.  It is kind of like asking them if they do much spintronics work. A simple publication search on 'perovskite' 'magnetoresistance' 'Mn' yields a number of articles. A place to start might be 
Magnetic and magnetoresistance properties in rhombohedral (La1-xK+MnO3)-Mn-x perovskite-type compounds
By: Boudaya, C; Laroussi, L; Dhahri, E; et al.
JOURNAL OF PHYSICS-CONDENSED MATTER  Volume: 10   Issue: 33   Pages: 7485-7492   Published: AUG 24 1998.